# How to use pbrt-v3 core in my own project with visual studio after building successfully?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, pbrt

I have been built pbrt-v3, and I want to use for my own project for learning.
But when I add addition include floder '**/core', and add the 'libpbrt.lib' to  additional dependencies.There is an error redefine 'PBRT_CONSTEXPR' as the follow image.[image]

How to solve this problem?
thanks.